# PDF created using JRXML template does not render Service Mark Symbol ℠ in the static text field

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a jrxml template to create PDF. It has a static text field with symbols like TradeMark, Copyright and ServiceMark. The TradeMark and Copyright symbols are rendered properly in the PDF but not ServiceMark.
I use Jasper v6.16.0 and Times New Roman font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Times New Roman font doesn't seem to include a glyph for the [service mark character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2120/index.htm).  Therefore you'll need to use a different font to render the symbol in PDF.

You can either use a different font for the whole text (for instance the DejaVu Sans font included in the [JasperReports fonts jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts) does have a glyph for the service mark symbol), or create a font set so that the text uses Times New Roman for letters/digits/etc and only uses DejaVu Sans (or another font) for characters that Times New Roman doesn't support.

Such a font set would look something like this in the font extension:

```
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Times New Roman">
        <normal>...path.../Times New Roman.ttf</normal>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
    
    <fontSet name="Times New Roman Font Set">
        <family familyName="Times New Roman"/>
        <family familyName="DejaVu Sans">
            <excludedScript>LATIN</excludedScript>
        </family>
    </fontSet>  
</fontFamilies>
```